# Run Flume master on Windows

Tags: windows, service, cloudera, flume

I'm able to run a Cloudera Flume node on Windows but I can't get a Flume master running.
Is this possible and how can you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible within windows unless you are willing to consider a virtual linux/unix box to act as the Flume master.

I have not spent any time researching Cygwin as a possible solution.

Comment: Already thought it wasn't possible but due to my time limit I don't need it anymore.